# Extracting Zip file save to disk

Tags: c#, zip

I have a zip file at a URI (such as http://www.abc.com/a.zip) that I would like to open and save a file from it to disk.  Is there a way in C# to open it without saving it to disk and then saving a file from it to disk?

Thanks,

Sachin

Comment: Where are you suppose to open the file from? To unzip the file it needs to be save to a temp folder at first or something simular, can't you just save it to a temporary folder, take the file, then remove the zip file?

Comment: Google will show you there are many open source Zip Libraries, e.g. http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example of the extracting the zip file without saving the archive to the file system using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/).

```
private static void ExtractFromUrl(Uri uri, string directoryPath)
{
    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        var data = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var zipFile = ZipFile.Read(memoryStream))
        {
            zipFile.ExtractAll(directoryPath);
        }                
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [ZipFile .Net Framework 4.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class or [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) API.

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(zipPath, extractPath);
```

EDIT: You can prepare a stream or obtain byte array of URL via method of `WebClient` class.

```
string urlStr = "https://xyz.com/sample.zip";

 using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
  {
   byte []bytes=client.DownloadData(urlStr);
   using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
   {
    using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ms))
    {
     zip.ExtractAll(@"C:\csnet");
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: the question is if there is a way to _not_ save it to disk first.

Comment: Incidentally, I prefer the DotNetZip approach.  I installed .Net 4.5 and VS 2012 earlier this week and it caused me too many problems so I uninstalled it.